# How to add multiple implementations to one service in vnext startup file?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have something like this in my startup file:

```
services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

which works as expected. However, I need to use another service in this implementation e.g.
SomeOtherService. Is there a way to add both to one service?

i.e. I have this:

```
public SomeController(ILoggerFactory factory, ISomeService someService)
```

I want this:

```
public SomeController(ILoggerFactory factory, ISomeService someService, ISomeOtherService someOtherService)
```

is this possible or should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `AddTransient` multiple times :)

```
services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeOtherService>();
```

Answer to the updated question:

Add an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter:

```
public SomeController(ILoggerFactory factory, IEnumerable<ISomeService> multipleServices)
```

Comment: Doh! My bad, I don't think I explained that properly. Please see the updated q. Thanks for the quick answer btw.

Comment: Makes sense thank you for updating the answer, it worked for me. I am just curious why this also works: public SomeController(ISomeOtherService someOtherService, ISomeService someService,  ILoggerFactory factory) without making the modifications to startup (ordering in the signature is important)

Comment: (1) What's the relation between `ISomeService` and `ISomeOtherService`? (2) What are the registrations?

Comment: ISomeService and ISomeOtherService both implement ISomeBaseService. I used your answer for my issue, and in my startup someservice and someotherservice both implement ISomeBaseService, then the enumerable you showed, uses ISomeBaseService. In my comment above, I only need addTransient<ISomeService, SomeService). When the controller is called, it figured out how to map them, multiple implementations - somehow - which is what I was curious about.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, I ended up with:
services.AddTransient<ISomeBaseService, SomeService>();
services.AddTransient<ISomeBaseService, SomeOtherService>(); and the controller - IEnumerable<ISomeBaseService> multipleServices, then I just use whatever I need. I noticed however that if I left my startup as services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>() and my controller - public SomeController(ISomeOtherService someOtherService, ISomeService someService, ILoggerFactory factory) it also worked. I just wasn't sure how or why. The ordering in the signature matters as well.

Comment: Victor, I've emailed you more detail. Hope that helps. We can update these comments based on our exchange.

Comment: If IService registered multiple times which one will be picked by framework? What if I wanna override the implementation one class registered inside framework? Means there will an existing IServiceX registered by framework and I need to override this.

Comment: If you call `GetService<IService>` you get the last registered implementation. Call `GetService<IEnumerable<IService>>` and you get all the registrations